# Setting a subview in UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, subview

EDIT: This question is due to a big lack of understanding how Interface Builder and properties in classes works.

Why can't i just set `self.mySubView = anoterhView;` like one can set `self.view = anotherView;` ?

```
## .h
@interface TestController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIView *mySubView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *mySubView;

##.m

@implements TestController

@synthesize mySubView;

- (void)viewDidLoad { 

    AnotherController *anotherController = [[AnotherController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    anotherView = anotherController.view;

    // if i do
    self.view = anotherView;
    // result: replaces whole view with anotherView

    // if i instead do
    self.mySubView = anotherView;
    // result: no change at all

    // or if i instead do:
    [self.mySubView addSubview:anotherView];
    // result: mySubView is now displaying anotherView

}
```

NOTE: I'm using interfacebuilder. I'm sure everything is hooked up allright because self.view, and self.mySubView addSubview: is working allright..

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. In interfacebuilder as a subview to self.view i've got mySubView. It's hooked up as an IBOutlet to the property set in the controller. like you can see in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it automatically appear on your `self.view` you need to overwrite your setter method, e.g.:

```
- (void)setMySubView:(UIView *)view {
    [mySubView removeFromSuperview];  // removing previous view from self.view
    [mySubView autorelease];
    mySubView = [view retain];
    [self.view addSubview: mySubView]; // adding new view to self.view
}
```

Comment: Smart, but not what i had in mind. I want to set a specific subview which self.view is holding.

Comment: Do you mean that you have drop some View on your UIViewController's view, and you want to replace that view (from IB) with different view from code? As I can understand, your need to do: 
1. save current view.frame: CGRect mySubViewFrame = [mySubView frame];
2. remove and put new subview - I have wrote how to do it
3. set new frame for new view: [mySubView setFrame:mySubViewFrame];

Comment: lots of juggling, but acceptable. i'm not clicking "accept" as i hope for an explanation on why or easier solution, but gonna stick with yours for now. thanks

Comment: Please have a look at my try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199737/setting-a-subview-in-uiviewcontroller/#answer-2208087

Answer (score 1):

**mySubview** is a property which is a reference to an UIView object. So when you assign an *UIView* object to it, you are merely changing what **mySubview** is referring to and no more as in this case,

```
self.mySubview = anotherView;
```

The original UIView object that **mySubview** was referring to is still referred to within **view**'s *subviews* property. Nothing changes.

But when you add **anotherView** as a subview of **mySubview**, **anotherView** belongs to the view hierarchy and is displayed on screen. So this works.

```
view (parent of) mySubview (parent of) anotherView
```

However when you assign **anotherView** directly to the **view**, You not only change the UIView object **view** was referring to but it also adds itself to the parentView. This is handled by *UIViewController*.

```
self.view = anotherView;
```

Your ***setCurrentView*** should be more or so like this,

```
- (void) replaceSubview:(UIView *)newView {
  CGRect frame = mySubview.frame;

  [mySubview removeFromSuperview];
  self.mySubview = newView;

  [self.view addSubview:newView];
  newView.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: i'l give it a spin on monday. thanks a lot! looks like a proper solution.

Comment: And what the difference between this solution and mine?

Answer (score 0):

As a response to what @beefon said. This works kind of as expected, but background-color is transparent. It doesen't respond either... buttons do not get pressed etc..

```
- (void)setCurrentView:(UIView *)newView {
    /*      1. save current view.frame: CGRect mySubViewFrame = [mySubView frame]; 
            2. remove and put new subview - I have wrote how to do it 
            3. set new frame for new view: [mySubView setFrame:mySubViewFrame];      */ 
    CGRect currentViewFrame = [currentView frame];
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
    [currentView autorelease];
    currentView = [newView retain];
    [self.view addSubview:currentView];
    [currentView setFrame:currentViewFrame]; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your instance variable needs to be a property in order to use the dot. syntax, use:

```
@Property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView* subview;
```

in the header, and use:

```
@synthesize subview;
```

in the main file.

In order to set a UIView using the dot. syntax you need to make it a property. This also allows you to set the `subview`'s properties outside the class.

Comment: i can't really see the difference between what you wrote and what i wrote.. if difference, could you explain?

Comment: Well I was elaborating with my own twist. If he accepts yours then I will delete my answer